# Calendar Vue.JS Issue with displaying months in HTML

Tags: vue.js

Hi so I want to create a calendar with Vue.JS
The main problem I have right now is when clicking a button that is set up to use a function that assigns a variable to a month it is not displayed on my HTML part.

also, this button subtracts a month from the current one, in Console.log everything works perfectly I'm having a problem with putting it up into HTML.

If there is a much easier way to do so I would definitely take that as an option as well.

all help is appreciated.

Please see the code below:

> 

```
  <div class="right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" v-on:click="test">
      Previous
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <h4>{{ this.textMonth }}</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="left">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>




> let CurrentDate = new Date();
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      meeting: this.meeting,
      Month: this.Month,
      textMont: this.textMonth
    };
  },
```

> 

```
     methods: {
   test() {
      CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() - 1);
      this.Month = CurrentDate.getMonth();
      this.textMonth = date.toLocaleString("default", { month: "long" });

      //console.log(CurrentDate.getMonth());
      console.log(this.Month);
      return this.Month;
    },
```

Comment: Hi, it's related to your issue but please use `date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })` instead of that dreadful switch-case 

Comment: Lovely!<3 thanks! now I need to figure out the issue part :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because you are using arrow function in the `data` method. I think you should use a regular anonymous function.

Check this out: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as created: () => console.log(this.a) or vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod()). Since an arrow function doesn’t have a this, this will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function.

BTW, it seems like you are trying to reach `this.Month` in the `data` method. If is that a prop, first you should add a `props` property to the object, second, you should give it a different and unique name.